# Clarifications regarding Riesz's lemma

Tags: functional-analysis

After reading through related questions, the answer to the following two questions still evades me:

In the proof provided [here](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/fun/riesz_lemma.pdf) for Riesz's lemma, it states:

> In a Hilbert spaces $Y$ , given a non-dense subspace $X$, there is $y \in Y$ with $||y|| = 1$ and $\inf_{x\in X} ||x − y|| = 1$, by taking $y$ in
> the orthogonal complement to $X$.

My questions are:

1. Why are we so interested in the value $1$? And can't it be that $\inf_{x\in X} ||x − y||>1$?
2. How exactly can I see that this $1$ is obtained? I tried: $$||x-y||^2=|\langle x-y,x-y \rangle|=|\langle x,x \rangle -2Re \langle x,y\rangle+\langle y,y \rangle|=|\langle x,x \rangle +\langle y,y \rangle|$$ but now what? How do I show that the infimum is $1$? Do I just take $x=0$? If so - why bother mentioning that $y$ is in the orthogonal complement to $X$ (the equality works without this)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed intended as something trivial. Obviously, in Hilbert space, you can take a $y\in X^\bot$ and the computation you wrote shows that
$$\tag{1}\inf_{x\in X} \lVert x-y\rVert=\lVert y\rVert.$$
There is nothing special about $\lVert y\rVert$ being $1$, it is only important that it is some fixed value different from $0$.

In a Banach space, it is not so easy to solve the optimization problem $\inf_{x\in X} \lVert x-y\rVert$, because you have no notion of orthogonality. In particular, it is unclear whether there are $y$ such that (1) holds. This is the whole point of the Riesz lemma, which is meaningful in Banach spaces, and which gives an approximate answer to this question.